# Event when message was consumed from queue

Tags: rabbitmq

We use `event-exchange` plugin for RabbitMQ to receive events about connections are opened/closed: https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html

Are there any plugins or mechanics to receive events when any message was consumed from specific queue?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you are describing is pretty typical and is simply implemented by letting the consumer publish a new message regarding the outcome of the previous one.

You can pretty much see it as a pipeline:

```
PublisherA ----> QueueA ----> ConsumerA ----> QueueB ----> SinkHole
```

Letting the broker do it has little meaning as it is not aware of the outcome of the message consumption (was it processed properly?). Moreover, as Lutz Horn underlines, this might cause an endless loop. For rejected or expired messages, you can look at [dead-letter exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).